# "PostGIS Error: type “geography” does not exist" when using psql

Tags: postgresql, postgis, psql

I'm creating a .sql file to create a new database.  A couple of my tables are utilizing the Postgis extension.  When I attempt to create the database from the commandline:

```
psql location < location.sql
```

it fails on the tables that contain columns that are geography datatypes.  When I psql into the database:

```
psql location
```

and copy paste the create table code from my .sql file, it creates the table fine.  I feel like I'm missing a small but important step here

I've been playing around with my .sql file but have had no luck getting around this error

Here's the script I'm using to create the database:

```
dropdb location
createdb location
psql -d location -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
psql -d location -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;"
psql location < location.sql
```

and here's the snippet from the location.sql file for the table that it's failing on:

```
create table public.fips (
    fips_id bigserial,
    state_code char(2),
    county_code char(3),
    county_subdivision_code char(5),
    place_code char(5),
    consolidated_city_code char(5),
    longitude double precision,
    latitude double precision,
    geo_point geography,
    area_name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (fips_id)
);
```

geo_point is the one that it's complaining about.

Comment: Does the search_path at this point in the script include public?  You could try changing the data type to public.geography or update the search_path.

Comment: hmmmm lemme try adding the public. prefix to geography.  From within the database, it looks like the search_path includes public

Comment: location=# show search_path;
        search_path
---------------------------
 "$user", public, topology
(1 row)

Comment: ahhhh That did it!  I prefixed the geography with public. and it worked fine.  Thank you!

Comment: Your script may change the search_path for the session, though, so looking at it from a different session won't help.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I needed to prefix the geography datatype with public.

Comment: Maybe accept your own answer so that it's clear that this was solved.

Comment: After an hour of debugging this was the thing that helped me. For some reason it wasn't necessary for another version of postgres/postgis.